# Convert RTP/UDP Stream to HTTP with ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp, ffserver

As you may know, **Android** uses a strange implementation of RTP - It can only play low bitrate RTP streams. On the other hand, it can play **Full HD HTTP stream** flawlessly.

I'm trying a workaround for this problem: As stated in the title, using ffmpeg to convert the RTP/UDP stream to HTTP.

I've already compile ffmpeg for android, but I'm having difficulties configuring the *ffserver.conf*.

1. Is it possible to achieve what I want with ffmpeg?
2. I dont need any transcoding, will it use lots of the processor/memory?
3. Can you help me with these configurations?

I receive a udp/rtp multicast stream:

- udp://@239.192.1.31:1234 or rtp://@239.192.1.31:1234 - TV channels

I want to output to HTTP:

- http://127.0.0.1:8090/stream.mp4

Thank you in advance
inversus

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Is it even possible to launch and stop a linux program like ffserver from inside android application?

Comment: It is Alexey, I followed the instructions from this post http://rxwen.blogspot.com/2010/05/use-ffmpeg-to-setup-streaming-server-on.html and was able to run ffserver from the command line using adb shell. I could only stream an audio file though, the mp4 video was apparently corrupt.

Comment: I have not  tested but this should give u a headstart : ffmpeg -i rtp://@239.192.1.31:1234 -acodec copy -vcodec copy http://127.0.0.1:8090/stream.mp4

Answer (score -2):

```
#LOKAL
#EXTINF:-1 ,Lokal-100 TVRI
rtp://@239.1.1.37:8196
#EXTINF:-1 ,Lokal-101 METROTV
rtp://@239.1.1.19:8088
#EXTINF:-1 ,Lokal-102 CNN INDONESIA
rtp://@239.1.1.241:9362
#EXTINF:-1 ,Lokal-103 TVONE
rtp://@239.1.1.31:8160
#EXTINF:-1 ,Lokal-104 TRANSTV
rtp://@239.1.1.27:8136
#EXTINF:-1 ,Lokal-105 TRANS7
rtp://@239.1.1.29:8148
#EXTINF:-1 ,Lokal-106 SCTV
rtp://@239.1.1.21:8100
#EXTINF:-1 ,Lokal-107 INDOSIAR
rtp://@239.1.1.17:8076
#EXTINF:-1 ,Lokal-108 ANTV
rtp://@239.1.1.15:8064
#EXTINF:-1 ,Lokal-109 RCTI
rtp://@239.1.1.23:8112
#EXTINF:-1 ,Lokal-110 GLOBAL TV
rtp://@239.1.1.13:8052
#EXTINF:-1 ,Lokal-111 MNCTV
rtp://@239.1.1.25:8124
#EXTINF:-1 ,Lokal- Kompas TV
rtp://@239.1.1.197:9156
#EXTINF:-1 ,Lokal- NET TV
rtp://@239.1.1.119:8688
```

Comment: please modify your answer in order to be more readable adding more information to your solution